# Would aliens invalidate Christianity as we know it?

Tags: humanity

If we discover other intelligent life forms in the universe, would this change Christianity in any way or not?

For the sake of the argument, let's presume we will find human-like life in a newly discovered planet in our solar system.

Comment: I sometimes find it difficult to find intelligent life on this planet, so I'm not even thinking about the possibility of intelligent life on other planets.

Comment: Do you intend asking for answers from a particular point of view? A literalist view of the Bible might conceivably have some problems; less literal interpretations would adapt!

Comment: It would certainly invalidate a few specific denominations that affirmatively teach that God created mankind *on this world and nowhere else,* but the Bible doesn't actually say that, so of course there are other branches of Christianity that hold other views on the subject.

Comment: @ Narnian Cannot disagree with that argument. Doesn't make one little bit of difference since intelligence is subjective anyway.

Comment: General philosophical or sociological questions are off-topic unless clearly asking for a doctrinal answer.See: [On-topic and constructive examples](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/779/on-topic-and-constructive-examples). But this is perfectly acceptable in chat, and oh, look! [Someone created a whole cat room for this type of question](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11704/would-christianity-survive-if)!

Comment: Suggested (fictional) reading: C. S. Lewis' [Space Trylogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Trilogy)

Comment: Maybe you have already seen this newly created chat room: [Would Christianity Survive If ...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11704/would-christianity-survive-if) I created that room because recently these questions interest me, however, they are almost always off-topic for the main site because they are either primarily opinion based or are general philosophical/sociological or both.

Comment: Highly related: [Does the Bible make any allusions to life on other planets?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1051/4188)

Comment: Related are [these posts also here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5443/has-the-catholic-church-ever-voiced-its-view-on-the-possibility-of-aliens-exist) and [here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4898/do-any-denominations-have-official-doctrine-regarding-humans-on-other-planets/5873#5873)

Answer (score 3):

It wouldn't change Christianity it all.  The Bible does not suggest that it contains all knowledge and all revelation.  There is a lot it does not reveal.

The presence of other intelligent life elsewhere in the universe would not change our own reality, which includes the following:

1. The Eternal Triune God created the universe of time, space and matter and everything in it.
2. Mankind was created in the image of God.  (Genesis 1:26-27)
3. Mankind sinned against God and thereby incurred God's punishment.  (Genesis 3)
4. God the Son, the Third Person of the Trinity, entered into creation through the virgin birth and then received the name Jesus (Yeshua/God saves).
5. Jesus died on the Cross to take upon Himself the punishment incurred by us.
6. By faith in Jesus, Christ's work on the Cross is credited to our account, freeing us from the penalty of sin and making us sons and daughters of God.
7. There is a final judgment for every person where those who follow Christ are rewarded and those who reject Christ will pay the penalty for sin themselves.

This is the reality for us.  The reality for other intelligent life would have no impact on our reality, other than that our reality would acknowledge that there was other intelligent life.

Is it impossible for God to enter into His creation again?  No.  It wouldn't matter to us if He did, though.

So, no, Christianity would not change at all.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question!
One that I've wondered from time to time.

My thought is this: Had we (human beings) not rebel against God, and instead follow His plan for us, we probably would have reached the technological advances that allow us to travel between galaxies today.  And yes, we probably would find other sentient beings in this vast universe that God has created for us (if not alongside with us).

Think about it, earth is but a speck of dust compared to the universe, why did God put us here and the stars out there if He didn't mean for us to reach it?

I'm sorry if this answer slightly violate the StackExchange rule because it is purely my speculation, but I am excited when I think this way because it makes me look forward to the future of what we may do with Christ as our King.  I believe science and technology will have their place in the new Heaven and Earth.

Answer (score 2):

### NO!

***Why?*** The Bible never say that we are the only people in this universe.

The Bible was written for men on this planet Earth and Jesus came for the people on this planet Earth. Man is the center of interest in the Bible. God created man and when man failed to remain righteous, God came down to planet Earth to die for the people in this Earth. That's all the Bible records. It has no reference to any other life on other planets. The Bible never say that we are the only people created in his own image nor there are others. The Bible is simply silent on this. Hence, the Bible can't be wrong in any case, whether aliens are discovered or not.

Even if aliens are discovered today, that won't change a thing. Who knows if God created other human on another planet, who also failed like us and Jesus already died for them also. However, it is irrelevant for us.

Comment: So what you're saying is, he failed with man on this planet so he conceivably gave it another shot on another one somewhere else.

Comment: @Matt I meant nothing. It's just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what does what else God may have created in the Universe have to do with what happened here on Earth?

God is sovereign he can create as many planets and people as he desires to fulfill his wants.

Whether or not he decides to extend his great love to multiple planets and peoples makes absolutely no difference in our relationship to him.

It seems to me that to even think that we are the only ones God could or even does love is sort of egotistical.

Looking at what I've written it may seem that I'm scolding or deriding, but that is not the case. I am simply stating my point of view and do not in any way wish to cast aspersions on anyone.

Answer (score 0):

There are Christians that have already discovered other intelligent life forms.
Some, like Ria Kotze ('Journey Beyond Tomorrow), believe that the angel that anounced the birth of Jesus was"the lord of Capricorn Command".
Jesus, they say, arrived on a "specially constructed interdimensional starship of indesceibable beauty" - the Star of Bethlehem.

For these Christians it was the discovery of earthlings by aliens that led to Christianity.
So the experts in these matters would surely agree with the mainstream Christians.
Discovering aliens would not change the plans in place for Christianity.